# adding jenkins pipeline triggers on agent node

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

i am trying to adding trigger to my pipeline file

```
pipeline {
agent {
    node {
      label 'Deploymentserver' 
      triggers {
        cron('H 09 * * 1-5')
      }  
   
    }
  
}
```

This code gives the error:

```
WorkflowScript: 22: Invalid config option "triggers" for agent type "node". Valid config options are [label, customWorkspace] @ line 22, column 11.
         triggers {
```

Then i tried to put it outside the agent asuming i wont work but just to test

```
pipeline {
agent {
    node {
      label 'Deploymentserver' 
 
   
    }
   
}
triggers {
        cron('H 09 * * 1-5')
}
```

It doesn't give any errors, but it dont trigger my pipeline either.
It seems that trigger option is not support in agent node.

it is a declarative pipeline integrated with bitbucket. How can i get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You second attempt is the correct syntax.
As you can see in the [Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers) the correct location for the `triggers` as at the same level of the `agent` directive:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'Deploymentserver'
    }
    triggers {
        cron('H 09 * * 1-5')
    }
    stages {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Therefore the configuration is not the issue and should work as expected.

One reason that is might causing you issues is that you must run the pipeline at least once (manual or automated) after adding the trigger configuration in order for the configuration to take effect.
You can go into the job configuration in the Jenkins UI and validate you see there the cron trigger settings, if so your pipeline trigger is configured properly.